# Two descriptions of Valence Bond Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules, quantum-chemistry

I am trying to understand theoretically Valence Bond Theory from the first principles of Quantum Mechanics and suitable approximations. I am a mathematician with shaky bases in Quantum Mechanics.

Let me consider the simplest case, the molecule $H_2$.

As I understand them, our basic assumptions are that the nuclei are so heavy that we can consider them fixed, and also that we can in first approximation neglect the Coulomb repulsion of the electron. The system is then just described by the wave function of a pair of electrons.
An electron is described by a unit vector in $L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes V$ where $V$ is a dimension $2$ space for the spin, and since electrons are Fermion, two electrons are described
as an **anti-symmetric** vector in $(L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes V)\otimes (L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes V)$.
Example of such vectors are for example **symmetric** function in $L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ tensor the unit **anti-symmetric** vector in $V \otimes V$. Let us consider pairs of electrons described by such a vector and let's forget about the spin. So we'll describe a pair of electrons as
$$(1)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \psi_A({\bf r}_1) \otimes \psi_B ({\bf r}_2) + \psi_B({\bf r}_1) \otimes \psi_A({\bf r}_2)$$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes L^2(\mathbb R^3)$, where $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ are orbital integral  for the hydrogen atom $A$ and $B$ respectively. For instance, $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ could both be the 1s orbital of their respective atoms, meaning that up to normalization constants, $\psi_A({\bf r}_1) = e^{-||{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_A||}$ and $\psi_B({\bf r}_2) = e^{-||{\bf r}_2-{\bf r}_B||}$, where ${\bf r}_A$ and ${\bf r}_B$ are the fixed positions of the nuclei of the hydrogens atoms A and B. This description of a molecular orbital is
the one given in this [text](http://alpha.chem.umb.edu/chemistry/ch612/documents/VBTheory.pdf), and I believe I understand it well.

But in most courses of quantum chemistry, another description, simpler but less easy to understand for me, is given. Namely, one consider just one electron, assuming the other is the same, with wave function $$ (2)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \psi_A({\bf r}) + \psi_B({\bf r}).$$
In the first case, the wave function is a symmetric function 6 variables, in the second case a function of 3 variable. My question is

> How does one pass from the description (1) of the molecular orbital to the description (2)?
>   What reasoning, what approximations are involved?

My idea was to describe the Hamiltonians in situation (1) and (2), and to compute the expected energy of our wave functions in both situations, and to compare them. The Hamiltonian in situation (2) is (in atomic units) 
$$H_{(2)} = \frac{-1}{2} \nabla + V_A({\bf r}) + V_B({\bf r})$$
This is logical if one neglects the interaction between the two electrons, and this is what is used for computation in the courses I have seen.

The Hamiltonian in situation (1) is, I guess,
$$H_{(1)} = \frac{-1}{2} (\nabla_1 \otimes 1) + \frac{-1}{2} (1 \otimes \nabla_2) + V_A \otimes 1+ V_B \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes V_A + 1 \otimes V_B.$$ 
Is that right? Anyway, when I try to compare the level of energies of our wave function (1) and (2) using $H_{(1)}$ and $H_{(2)}$ I get nowhere.

Can someone help me? A reference where is explained in some details would also make me happy.